# Safari browser block display issue

Tags: html, css, safari

I am not sure what exactly is causing this issue . I am sespecting the display mode is not the same for Safari.
I have a left sidebar that extends to rest of the remaining containing block height. but it does not work on safari only. tried it on IE, FF and Chrome and works as expected.

> the chrome version (good one)

[image]

> The safari version

[image]

And here's the computed CSS for the containing class:

```
background-color: rgb(241, 241, 242);
border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
float: none;
font-family: Whitney, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 950.25px;
line-height: 20px;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
position: relative;
right: 1044px;
width: 236px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in 3 different  tags, set the height in %.
E.g.

```
div .left {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

If it doesn't extend all the way down just set min-height to 200%.
Think that should work, but don't know about safari display modes.